# What do I need to complete my Mass Effect Trilogy collection?

Tags: mass-effect-series

I got the Mass Effect Trilogy on PS3 (UPC 014633198065) for Christmas.  This came with some DLC content included, but it seems there's still a lot I don't have.  The remaining DLC is a little bit confusing, as it seems some items can be bought either individually or as part of certain bundles.

So, I'd like to know what is the minimum number of purchases I would need to make to fully complete my Mass Effect Trilogy collection with all DLC?

Answer (score 13):

It looks like the Mass Effect Trilogy contains the following games;

**Mass Effect**

- Bring Down the Sky

**Mass Effect 2**

- Cerberus Network Pass
- Kasumi (Stolen Memory)
- Overlord
- Lair of the Shadow Broker
- Blood Dragon Armour

**Mass Effect 3**

---

This leaves quite a few DLCs unaccounted for, and I'm not sure if all of them are available on the Playstation 3. It is worth noting that *many* but not all of these DLCs do not influence the game story and are purely aesthetic, adding individual items or a group of upgrades/achievements.

I have marked the DLC containing story content in **bold**.

I have marked the DLC content for which I can find confirmation stating it is available on the Playstation 3 in *italics* - this doesn't mean that the others aren't available, just that I didn't find anything obvious stating they were.

The missing DLCs are;

**Mass Effect**

- **Pinnacle Station**

**Mass Effect 2**

- **The Price of Revenge** (Requires access to Cerberus Network)
- Normandy Crash Site (Requires access to Cerberus Network)
- Cerberus Weapons and Armours (Requires access to Cerberus Network)
- Arc Projector (Requires access to Cerberus Network)
- **Firewalker Pack** (Requires access to Cerberus Network)
- *Alternate Appearance Pack 1* (Included in N7 Complete Arsenal Bundle)
- *Equalizer Pack* (Included in N7 Complete Arsenal Bundle)
- *Aegis Pack* (Included in N7 Complete Arsenal Bundle)
- *Firepower Pack* (Included in N7 Complete Arsenal Bundle)
- *Genesis* (Requires access to Cerberus Network)
- **Arrival**
- Alternate Appearance Pack 2

It is likely that all of the content that 'Requires access to Cerberus Network' would be available with any copy of the game which includes a Cerberus network access code (which *is* included with the PS3 release of Mass Effect 2).

There is also a long list of promotional content which is no longer available, or only available by purchasing the collectors edition. Some of these items are available individually on PlayStation Network;

- Collectors Weapons and Armour
- Inferno Armour
- Terminus Weapon and Armour
- Recon Hood
- Sentry Interface
- Umbra Visor
- M-29 Incisor
- *Recon Operations Pack* (Included in N7 Complete Arsenal Bundle)
- *N7 Complete Arsenal Bundle*

**Mass Effect 3**

- ***Extended Cut DLC***
- **From Ashes**
- ***Omega***
- ***Leviathan***
- *Retaliation* (Multiplayer DLC)
- Earth (Multiplayer DLC)
- Rebellion (Multiplayer DLC)
- Resurgence (Multiplayer DLC)

Again, there are quite a few DLCs that only add individual items or cosmetic content, it is not clear if any of these will be available on PlayStation Network and some of these require specific versions of Mass Effect 3 (such as the N7 Collectors edition);

- Firefight Pack
- Groundside Resistance Pack
- Alternate Appearance Pack 1
- AT-12 Raider Shotgun (Pre-order bonus via Origin only. *Should* also be in the Leviathan DLC on PS3)
- Chakram Launcher (*Should* also be in the Omega DLC on PS3)
- M-55 Argus (*Should* also be in the Leviathan DLC on PS3)
- M-90 Indra (PC only)
- N7 Collectors Edition Pack
- N7 Warfare Gear
- Reckoner Knight Armour
- Battlefield 3 Pack (Multiplayer Content)
- Collector Assault Rifle (Multiplayer Content)
- Premium Collectible Pack (Multiplayer Content)
- Recruitment Reward Pack (Multiplayer Content)

All in all, the story content is pretty much all available for the PlayStation 3 - I suspect that all of the content for Mass Effect 2 marked as 'requires Cerberus Network' will be available for the PS3 (although I found no confirmation) on account of Cerberus Network access being available on the PS3. I also suspect that all of the Mass Effect 3 multiplayer content would be available but again, I can't confirm this. It would be worth checking on PlayStation Network for anything you're missing - some (if not all) of the content you're missing should be available on there.

Comment: I think the "Requires Cerberus Network" content is actually *included* in the Cerberus Network DLC, which came with my edition of Mass Effect Trilogy.  A lot of those items look familiar from missions I've already played.

Comment: @Iszi the 'Cerberus Network' is not a DLC, it's an access code that authenticates the game and provides access to free DLC. It would make sense that all of the 'requires Cerberus network' DLCs are automatically downloaded when access to the Cerberus network is active though. I have reworded the answer a bit to reflect this.

Comment: Finally got to check the PlayStation Store to see what DLCs are available: Arrival, N7 Complete Arsenal Bundle, Aegis Pack, Appearance Packs 1 & 2, Cerberus Pack, Equalizer Pack, Firepower Pack, Recon Operations Pack, and Terminus Pack.  However, I still think some of the smaller packs are included as parts of the larger ones.  (Some DLCs are only $2, where others are $8 or more.)  If you have information on this, could you update your answer to address my request for completion of the collection with a "minimum number of purchases"?

Comment: Also, the N7 Arsenal is labeled as a "Bundle", though the Store entry doesn't say what is included.  I haven't looked at the Store for ME3 yet, since I haven't yet even loaded the game onto the console.

Comment: Terminus pack is not included in N7 Arsenal bundle on PS3, just thought I would correct the above, as I thought I was getting a better deal than I did..

Answer (score 2):

After digging deeper into the specs of the Trilogy edition, and searching some online references (particularly the [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/)) I've narrowed down a list of what needs to be bought to complete the collection.  There will be exclusions for pieces that are already part of the Trilogy bundle, and also for some DLCs not available on PS3.  Other exclusions may be components of "Bundle" packs.

Mass Effect 1:

- No DLCs needed.  (Pinnacle Station is not available on PS3)

Mass Effect 2:

- N7 Complete Arsenal Bundle
- Alternate Appearance Pack 2
- Arrival

Mass Effect 3 (Single Player)

- Extended Cut
- From Ashes
- Firefight Pack
- Leviathan
- Groundside Resistance Pack
- Alternate Appearance Pack 1
- Omega
- Citadel

Mass Effect 3 (Multiplayer)

- Resurgence Pack
- Rebellion Pack
- Earth
- Retaliation
- Reckoning