# Cerberus Network access: possible problems?

Tags: ps3, mass-effect-2

I read in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98921/what-do-i-need-to-complete-my-mass-effect-trilogy-collection) that Cerberus Network access is required for all DLC in ME2 and that this is included in the PS3 trilogy boxset, but I'm unsure what this actually means.

Do I need to do anything to activate this content, or is it all pre-included in the game as installed from the trilogy disc?

**Edit:**

So, I feel pretty dumb.. I checked the insert in my ME3 box and it had *two* codes on the back, one of which was for the ME2 Cerberus Network. I downloaded and installed that, and when I press the button to 'connect to EA servers' the text now changes to 'connected to EA servers'.

The Cerberus laptop to the right of the main menu screen still isn't open, but when I loaded the game I got emails about Zaeed, so I guess that is my problem solved :) Thanks karlina

Comment: When you start ME2, [is the 'Cerberus laptop' on the main menu open or closed](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-3-General-Discussion/Mass-Effect-Trilogy-and-Cerberus-Network-Activation/td-p/17856768)? If it is open, you should be connected to the Cerberus network, if it's closed and you've already entered any codes that came with your game, I'd contact EA support.

Comment: I would contact EA support and explain that you're unable to access Cerberus Network on a newly bought copy of the ME trilogy, it sounds like something may have been missing from your bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, as I have [discussed at length in this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/98924/27134) the Cerberus network and all of the related 'free' DLC that is available on the Cerberus network are included as part of the Mass Effect trilogy. For full details of everything else included in the PS3 trilogy package, see that link.

There are some reported issues with the codes [not being enabled](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Mass-Effect/Mass-Effect-2-PS3-Cerberus-Network-Code/td-p/30896515) when the trilogy was first released but this issue no longer seems to exist. There was also a couple of instances of the codes provided with the game being [expired](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=486091) and in these instances I would recommend you contact EA directly. If you in fact do not have a code, I would also contact EA directly for support.

Comment: Not sure - PC version has a "CD Key" type code to enable the Cerberus Network. If you're unable to authenticate with the Cerberus Network, or it is asking for a code that you do not have, I would recommend contacting EA support for assistance.

Comment: You should find that DLC like "The Price of Revenge", "Normandy Crash Site", etc are 'free' - if not then you're probably not authenticated with the Cerberus Network.