# How can I enumerate my installed DLCs on PS3?

Tags: ps3

> Related: [What do I need to complete my Mass Effect Trilogy collection?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98921/what-do-i-need-to-complete-my-mass-effect-trilogy-collection)

So, I've finally gotten the funds to fully complete my Mass Effect Trilogy collection. However, I know there were a few DLCs that I have already purchased - and I've forgotten which.

I'd rather not have to load each game and go through their menus (if there even are any available) to find out which ones have been installed. Is there a way, outside of in-game menus or links, to get a list of *all* DLCs installed on the PS3?

I've tried the Game Data Utility, but this does not list individual DLCs. It only shows one item called "[Game Name] DLC and Patches" and will not give any more granular detail.

Comment: Don't think there actually is a way, unfortunately. DLCs just get added to the "game data" folder, usually as a singular unit, and only the game can tell you if you have it all or  not.

Comment: Found it with help from Sony support. Ended up calling them anyway 'cause network was down and the error message was locking up my console.

Answer (score 2):

The list of installed DLCs is accessible from the console, but is not stored (in an easily-accessible manner) locally. You must be connected and signed in to PSN.

To access the Download List, take the following path from the main menu:

```
PlayStation Network -> Account Management -> Transaction Management -> Download List
```

A couple things are worth noting about this list:

- The list includes *all* DLCs purchased (or redeemed with a code) with your PSN account - not just the DLCs currently installed.
- This list *excludes* any DLCs which came pre-installed on a game disc (e.g.: [Bring Down the Sky](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Bring_Down_The_Sky), [Lair of the Shadow Broker](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Lair_of_the_Shadow_Broker)).