# One Still Missing Engineer

Tags: mass-effect

I am playing Bringing Down the Sky DLC for Mass Effect a second time. In this DLC we have to locate missing engineers.

I enabled the transmission tower, showed me the locations of all three survey stations on my map.

There is a problem with Survey Station 1. The engineer C. Hymes, I found her body, played the logs on how she died. In my Journal it registers as I found her body. This was the penultimate body I found. But in my journal it does not go grey with a check mark next to it.

Because of this it still shows "One Still Missing Engineer". And because of this I can not hand it over for completion.

Did I get massively glitched? I have installed both ME1 patches. My first playthrough I was able to complete it like normal. This is the plus game I started.

Is this glitch going to affect my ME2 playthrough? Is there anything I can do to fix this and turn the quest back in to the quest giver?

Comment: The [Mass Effect Wiki](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/X57:_Missing_Engineers) doesn't note any known glitches for this quest. Try going back and seeing if you can "Use" the corpse or the recording again. Maybe try leaving/re-entering the system and doing this task again. You might also have to wait until later on in the main DLC mission - the NPC you report to for mission closure is not available until the main Bring Down the Sky questline is finished.

Comment: Dunno what to say, then. If you're on PC, it might be time to use the console or something. I'm going to be re-playing the Mass Effect Trilogy myself soon-ish too (finally [completed my DLC collection](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/98921/what-do-i-need-to-complete-my-mass-effect-trilogy-collection) and just need to get the rest of Borderlands 2 wrapped up before I go back to ME), so I'll try to keep an eye out for this when I do.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a bug at all. It sounds to me like you needed to "Use" the corpse to trigger the find, as I'd suggested. (It just happened that the one corpse you didn't do this on wasn't the last one you found.) Am I misunderstanding your post? Where are you seeing a bug?

Comment: That definitely sounds like a UI issue, which technically isn't a bug. The game is functioning as the designers intended. It just so happens that the way they designed this particular mission was a bit unintuitive to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From @Iszi 's comments I have to post what happened. Hope you do not run into the same.

I first tackled the outpost where you land on X57. It is right behind you when you land. So found the body of Mendel. And how he died brutally.

Till then there were no stations marked on my map.

Then I took out the Fusion gun ahead of where I landed. Then repaired the transmission tower. Then went and got C Hymes at Survey Station 1. Recognized her death as a result of an explosion.

At this point the game did not mark her body as found. Which is why my question in the first place. I kept going back to the same station to make the game change her status to found.

Last I found the last survey station where Montoya should have been. Found all the clues to his vehicle. And then concluded that I found Montoya. But at that point there is a marker on your map about Montoya's dead body. Unless you pick it up even C. Hymes's body does not register as picked.

This is the crucial point that the Wikia article missed.

I went through with the mission, let Balak live. And then Simon is like all Where are my engineers? I was able to answer about two them found. He said please maybe the last one might make it.

Picked Montoya's body and Mission Accomplished. :-)

In my first one I did it the other way. And I tend to rely on my journal entries a lot.

Comment: I have a policy of always doing primary objectives *last*. So, when I got to X57, checking out the Survey Stations was the first thing on my to-do. I did notice that Montoya's objective did not get checked after I examined and looted his corpse. He was the second of the three engineers I found. Hymes was the last. When I found her, the entire Assignment completed. I don't know why Montoya wasn't getting checked, but he's checked now. I presume this means I should be able to give Simon a full report when I see him.

Answer (score 1):

Survey Station 2 has an interaction tag on east side of the bunker that says "faint footprints lead off to the east." I decided to go by foot east in case there were more clues, but the body was just due east, down in a ditch. I could have found it with the rover. I found the other two bodies first, with survey station 1 being last. It didn't register her as found at first, until I found Montoya.